# Can i install drivers for amd HD7950 on Mint 18+?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers

is there a way to install proprietary/open source drivers for AMD HD7950 on Mint 18+. I have tried to install the driver from amd's official site but driver partially fails at the install and after reboot it freezing at the boot logo. I know that it is officially not supported on the latest mint, but i was wondering if it is doable.

Answer (score 1):

The [proprietary driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86) stopped being updated a while ago and is no longer compatible with the X server used in recent distributions (including Mint 18). For a HD7950, you should use the `radeon` driver (in Mint, the [`xserver-xorg-video-radeon`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati) package; you’ll probably also need the [`linux-firmware`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware) package).

The only way you can use the proprietary driver is to downgrade your X server to an older release, and that’s not a good idea.

Comment: i am a bit of a noob, radeon drivers you mean [this](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx)?

Comment: I mean the `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` driver which is available by default in your distribution (in Mint, using the [Ubuntu packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati)).